# Are there any alternatives to Facebook's /{user}/home deprecated api?

Tags: facebook, rest, api, facebook-graph-api

[Facebook removed the `/{user}/home` api on October 6, 2015.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4)

I'm wondering if anyone knows if there are any alternative methods to access news feed data.

I've worked with [`/{user}/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed) but of course that only shows data for the currently logged in user.

I've tested with my wife to be sure and she can only she posts on her wall and I can only see posts on my wall and neither of us can see each others posts no matter what permissions are set on them.

I'd like to think that currently logged in user could access any data via the api that they could via the site (assuming they've granted the proper permissions of course.), but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Of course I am particularly interested in the news feed and I suspect that the there is no alternative but I don't want to give up yet.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to think that currently logged in user could access any data
>   via the api that they could via the site

No, that would be a privacy issue, because your app could access data/posts of users who did not even authorize your app and no one knows what you do with the data. So the answer is no, there is no alternative.

Comment: Well, I was assuming that both users had given the proper authorization to the app.  But this is about what I had assumed.  Thanks.